# Maximum call stack size exceeded when trying to submit form with JQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

So basically, i'm fairly new to programming web-applications and today i decided to create an log-in system. However there's one problem, when trying to validate the user's log-in credentials using AJAX i get the error: **"VM7707 jquery-3.5.0.js:8885 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"**.

If i've understood the cause to this problem right, there's a function calling itself or another one over and over again. I might be blind and dumb because i don't really know how to fix this problem, down below you can see a snippet of my code, this is the function that runs when i submit my login-form.

I have tried removing and changing the file-path that the function is supposed to call but the problem still stands. I also read that to avoid the problem you can sometimes write $('#loginForm')[0].submit, but that didn't work either.

This is my first time on stackoverflow so i'm sorry if there's something wrong with my way of adressing things, but i've been stuck on this hinder for over an hour now hehe.

Would be thankful if anyone would explain to me why it occurs in this case :) thanks.

```
JavaScript
$('#loginForm').submit(function() {
    $.post("./models/validateModel.php", {
        name: loginUsername,
        password: loginPassword
    }).done(function(data) {

        if (data === false) { //if the data isn't false i have a heading in validateModel.php
            console.log("Unsuccessful Login Attempt");
        }
    });
});
```

```
HTML
<form id="loginForm" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="loginUsername">Användarnamn</label>
      <input id="loginUsername" type="text" class="form-control" name="loginUsername">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="loginPassword">Lösenord</label>
      <input id="loginPassword" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" id="loginKnapp" class="btn btn-primary w-100 disabled" disabled>Logga In</button>
   <button type="button" id="registerButton" class="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-4">Inte Registrerad?</button>
</form>
```

```
Console
    VM10 jquery-3.5.0.js:8885 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size 
    exceeded
    at buildParams (VM10 jquery-3.5.0.js:8885)
    at buildParams (VM10 jquery-3.5.0.js:8913)
    at buildParams (VM10 jquery-3.5.0.js:8913)
    at buildParams (jquery-3.5.0.js:8913)
    at buildParams (jquery-3.5.0.js:8913)
    at buildParams (jquery-3.5.0.js:8913)
    at buildParams (jquery-3.5.0.js:8913)
    at buildParams (jquery-3.5.0.js:8913)
    buildParams @ jquery-3.5.0.js:8885
    buildParams @ jquery-3.5.0.js:8913
    buildParams @ jquery-3.5.0.js:8913
    buildParams @ jquery-3.5.0.js:8913
    buildParams @ jquery-3.5.0.js:8913
    buildParams @ jquery-3.5.0.js:8913
    buildParams @ jquery-3.5.0.js:8913

    VM10 jquery-3.5.0.js:5228 [Violation] 'submit' handler took 4843ms
```

Comment: `=` and `===` are not the same. The first is for assigning value for a variable the second is comparing values or references.

Comment: @norbitrial Thanks for pointing that out, i guess it's a common beginners mess-up, it didn't make any difference with the error tho. But thanks for the head's up :)

Comment: As an aside you should use `$.post` to send login data, but nothing in that snippet would cause an infinite loop. Is this the full code?

Comment: @ChrisG There's a bunch more code in this JS-file but the problem doesn't occur when i remove the snippet i just posted. Also, thanks for the heads up will definitely use post instead!

Comment: Check the console; does it show a bunch of XHRs? Or just one? Can you add the form HTML?

Comment: @ChrisG It doesn't seem like there are any XHRs, i turned the notifications on in console and only got violations because of the time it took and the original error.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace of your error from the console?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Alright, it'd be hard to post all 200 of the errors tho.

Comment: Just the first 10-15 or so

Comment: Are the  `loginUsername`, `loginPassword` values correct?

Comment: More importantly, where are these values coming from? The only explanation I can see is that somehow, accessing `loginUsername` submits the form maybe?

Comment: I went through those lines in `jquery-3.5.0.js` and it appears that `buildParams` indeed calls itself recursively.  There is definitely something to check about what values you are passing, it might be a bug in jQuery which could be reported

Comment: Thanks for all the help @ChrisG and  Anurag Srivastava there was a problem with the values as you expected, i got it working after some hair-pulling :P Thanks so much.